# How to send request from rest API to Windows Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, tcp

as the question says, how can I communicate from a rest API to Windows application. I have Windows application that connects to a linux server over TCP connection. This application manages multiple connections (around 7-8k tcp connection on different ports and keeps alive these connections all the time.). I have a mobile application that connects to rest API (APS.net C#) and works as expected. Now i want to send some more information from linux server to mobile client. How can I send a request from rest API to windows application and get response to send it to mobile application when requested from mobile. This communication between API and Windows application should be asynchronous and could handle around 7-8k connections without delay. How can i achieve this? Is it possible to achieve this using current architecture? or should I change it? I am willing to adopt any proposed architecture or new framework and any other programming language which serves the purpose good. Here is rough structure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try using [SignalR](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/11/01/how-to-use-signalr-in-ios-and-android-apps.aspx#targetText=For%20those%20who%20haven't,each%20other%20in%20real%20time), it allows for dual communication between client and serer

It uses websockets as its underlying connection and you can either send messages to all connected clients or a specific client.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr